# Unnest(String_to_array) conversion in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am migrating procedural structure of PostgreSQL code to Oracle. Is there any alternative function present in Oracle for PostgreSQL's `unnest(string_to_array)`?

```sql
select a.finalval
from   (select unnest(string_to_array(vturs_id, ',')) as finalval)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a table collection expression and, rather than using a delimited string, use a collection or `VARRAY` (like `SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST`):

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_VALUE as finalval
FROM   TABLE( SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST( 1, 2, 4 ) )
```

outputs:

> ```
> | FINALVAL |
> | -------: |
> |        1 |
> |        2 |
> |        4 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=2a88c14305664a0226b3537e3228d05a)*

If you have to use delimited string (don't) then you can use a recursive sub-query factoring clause to parse the string:

```sql
WITH test_data ( delimited_string ) AS (
  SELECT '1,2,40,-5,72' FROM DUAL
),
bounds ( delimited_string, start_idx, end_idx ) AS (
  SELECT delimited_string,
         1,
         INSTR( delimited_string, ',', 1 )
  FROM   test_data
UNION ALL
  SELECT delimited_string,
         end_idx + 1,
         INSTR( delimited_string, ',', end_idx + 1 )
  FROM   bounds
  WHERE  end_idx > 0
)
SELECT CASE end_idx
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR( delimited_string, start_idx )
       ELSE SUBSTR( delimited_string, start_idx, end_idx - start_idx )
       END AS finalval
FROM   bounds;
```

outputs:

> ```
> | FINALVAL |
> | :------- |
> | 1        |
> | 2        |
> | 40       |
> | -5       |
> | 72       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9dcaf736604078b0d83bb43f7c7f2093)*